# Extract columns by matching, rename, and assign value using AWK

Tags: awk, aggregate

I have a tab delimited csv file containing summary statistics for object lengths:

```
sampled. objs.  obj. min. len.  obj. mean. len. obj. max. len.  obj. std.
50  22  60  95  5
```

I want the information about minimum and maximum lengths by searching matching column headers `obj. min. len.` and `obj. max. len.`. I then want to create a new csv file, comma-delimited with new column headers to get the result

```
object_minimum,object_maximum
22,95
```

I first print the new headers. Then I tried retrieving the indices of the match and then extracting from the second row using these indices:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    cols="object_minimum:object_maximum"
    FS="\t"
    RS="\n"
    col_count=split(cols, col_arr, ":");
    for(i=1; i<=col_count; i++) printf col_arr[i] ((i==col_count) ? "\n" : ",");
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if(index($i,"obj. min. len.") !=0) {
        data["object_minimum"]=i;
        }
        if(index($i,"obj. max. len.") !=0) {
        data["object_maximum"]=i;
        }  
    }
}
END NR==1 {
    for (j=1; j<=col_count; j++) printf NF==data[j] ((i==col_count) ? "\n" : ",");
}
```

There could be more columns and in a different order so it is necessary to do the matching to find the position, and also I may have to select for more columns by changing `cols` and looking for more matches. I execute by running

```
awk -f awk_script.awk original.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: How are the column names separated from each other in the heading line? It looks as if maybe you have double-spaces between names and single-spaces within names? That's pretty nasty.  Are the columns in the data rows also separated by double-spaces? Which version of `awk` are you using? How do you plan to identify the input column names that must be extracted and the output column names that must be generated, and how do you plan to specify the order in which the output columns must appear?  Hmm; the `awk` script you show suggests the field separators are tabs — that's easier. Please confirm.

Comment: Setting `OFS = ","` might save some angst — the output field separator.  There again, it may have no benefit as you're likely to have write out the bits and pieces in multiple `printf` calls for a single line.

Comment: It is tab-delimited, the header names have spaces in them which I agree isn't nice, which is why they need to be changed. The order of columns and names of new columns is given by how I specify `cols`. I start by printing the column names in the comma-delimited format that I want. Then I need to extract and print the values below that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one working prototype, add formatting and error checking...

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS=, '
       NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                if($i=="obj. min. len.") min=i; 
                else if($i=="obj. max. len.") max=i; 
              print "min","max"}
       NR==2 {print $min,$max; exit}' file

min,max
22,95
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS=","}
     NR==1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){f[$i] = i}}  # fill array with header
     NR> 1 {print $(f["obj. min. len."]), $(f["obj. max. len."])}' file
```

Output:

```
22,95
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359699/74329

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: What aspect of the code shown requires GNU Awk as opposed to any other variant?  And it doesn't actually print the mapped headings, but is otherwise startlingly elegant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I usually only test it with GNU awk.

Comment: Fair enough — I don't think there's any code in it that depends on the GNU-ness of Awk.

Comment: nice, elegant solution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you for this hint. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, completely based on your shown samples only, written and tested in GNU `awk`. Created an `awk` variable named `sep="###"` this could be changed as per need too.

```
awk -v sep="###" '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
FNR==1{
  while(match($0,/ +obj\./)){
    val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    sub(/^ +/,"",val)
    line=(line?line:"")substr($0,1,RSTART-1)sep val
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  if(substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)!=""){
    line=line substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
  num=split(line,arr,sep)
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(arr[i]=="obj. min. len."){ min=i }
    if(arr[i]=="obj. max. len."){ max=i }
  }
  print "object_minimum,object_maximum"
  next
}
{
  print $min,$max
}
'  Input_file
```

***Logical explanation:*** Working on the very first line of Input_file. Then using `awk`'s `match` function to look for matches  `+obj\.` in current line. In this creating a variable which has values of matched and before matched values. Once all searching of specific regex is done(means all occurrences of matched regex are found). Then splitting newly created variable(which has value of first line with separators `###` assuming these are NOT present in your Input_file else change them to something else) into array. Finally going through all elements of that array and putting condition if a column is `obj. min. len.` then setting `min` variable value to that specific index number(which is actually field number for rest of the lines) and if value is `obj. max. len.` then setting `max` variable. After processing first line simply printing corresponding fields by doing `$min,$max`.